# Calculate landscape metrics over other raster column in R (landscapemetrics package)

Tags: r, raster, landscape

In R and using the landscapemetrics package, I am wanting to calculate landscape metrics of a raster file that I have that contains different vegetation types. When I import the raster file into R using the stack function, the file contains one layer with multiple levels (see attached image). [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAWkO.png)

Subsequently, when I run a function to calculate a landscape metric, or plot the raster, it works with the "Value" level/column (see second image attached). [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKXo9.png). Rather, I want it to calculate the metric over the "Vegetation_Type" level/column directly. However, I do not know how to do this. Currently, when I calculate for example the amount of core area for each vegetation type, it gives me the result in the form of a table that presents "class = 1-7" with the specific core area of that class, rather than "Vegetation_Type = Hummock". I want to have the "class" column with numbers 1-7 to be substituted by the vegetation types (e.g. Hummock, N, K etc.). Is there anyone who knows how to do this who can maybe help me?

Thank you so much in advance, and sorry for the unlogical post. I am still new here and do not really know how to best structure my questions!

Sincerely,

Jasper

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It's easier to help you if you make your question reproducible including data and your code which can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Have a look at https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5 and [mre]

Answer (score 0):

The `lanscapemetrics` package will always use the numeric ID of each class to make sure the output is type stable, i.e, always identical regardless of the input.

But, since the output is simply a `tibble`, you should be able to just join the information using e.g. `dplyr::left_join()`.